# Suggestion for organising SO: Hubs / Nexi

Tags: feature-request

a while back I posted a question regarding modulo:   [How to code a modulo (%) operator in C/C++/Obj-C that handles negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003232/how-to-code-a-modulo-operator-in-c-c-obj-c-that-handles-negative-numbers)

a few days ago I asked a related question... [C: How to wrap a float to the interval [-pi, pi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633177/c-how-to-wrap-a-float-to-the-interval-pi-pi)

yesterday I came across another identical question: [Mod of negative number is melting my brain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082917/mod-of-negative-number-is-melting-my-brain/1082938#1082938)

now,  as I understand, the existing mechanism is to link between these two questions by adding a comment to each containing the link.

can I suggest something?

it would be really nice if I could create a **HUB-NODE**,  label it 'modulo',  and then link it to both of these entries. and any other related ones I care to link.  It would be a one to many relationship.

So each question would show a list of all the hubs that map onto it.   click on one of them and it will take you to the hub which will show you a list of all the pointees of that hub.   maybe this could be a nicely ordered list, or a long page containing subheadings, categorisations and hyperlinks.  (ie sometimes a straight list isn't enough, further explanation to differentiate may be required)

if you allow users to  accrete points by creating and linking up these nodes, ... ie  if you provide the right structure, the whole thing should organise itself into shape.    you would need some peer review mechanism for validity of a node;  may be if it acquires five plus points it becomes  concrete.   and if it acquires five negative points it vanishes,  or gets marked for removal by a senior member.   and an established node  returns say 20 points to the person who established it.

now you could even step back;  say a node links to multiple objects. Each link  can point to a question, or even another node.

I think this model has a huge organisational potential;  it avoids the problem of top-down tree-based organisation, which always falls over as you end up having multiple points on the tree interfering with one another and duplicating.

Comment: So, what's the difference between a hub-node and a tag...?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you just described the "Related" sidebar. There are two sections: The first section is shown if there are any links to or from other questions on the same site. The second section, which is almost always shown, is automatically generated.

There is also the concept of a "tag wiki", for example here is the one for the "modulo" tag: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/modulo

> The modulo tag has no wiki, would you like to help us create it?

Users with sufficient reputation can edit the tag wiki to describe the "modulo" tag, which may include links to commonly asked questions.